# Approximating $e$ and the approximation error

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

To approximate $e$ one could approximate the following limits:

$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$$ or

$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$$

My questions: For given $n$, how many calculations are needed to approxmiate $e$ for each method?

I guess for the 2nd method we first need to evaluate $1/0!$ and then for $n=1$ we need to evaluate $1/1!$ and add this value to $1/0!$. So $1+2$ calculations. My answer would be $1+2n$.

For the 1st method I dont know.

And how can I approximate $\Delta_{app}(n):= e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and $\Delta_{app}(n):= e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$ respectively.

The hint is to use the mean value theorem for a suitable function $f$ on $[0,1]$ for the first method.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Lagrange remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html) of the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ at $x_0=0$, we have that there is $c\in(0,1)$ such that
$$e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}<\frac{3}{(n+1)!}.$$

As regards the difference $e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, you may show that for all $n\geq 1$,
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e <\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$ and therefore
$$e -\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n <\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n =  \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n} <\frac{e}{n}<\frac{3}{n}. $$

Comment: @user711482 Any comment from your side?

Comment: I don't see why I shouldnt be correct, thanks!